# How to lookup a value and project with condition in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is the query which was written to project examDetails and the condition is whatever values in userExamDetails should not be shown in examDetails. The $eq condition is not working here.

`db.getCollection('collectionOne').aggregate([
{'$match': { "user_id": ObjectId("5a1fb48c9815361dbe631974"), 'status': 1 }},
{   '$lookup': { 
      from: 'collectionTwo', 
      localField: 'package.ids',
      foreignField:'_id',
      as:'packageDetails' 
}},
{   '$lookup': { 
      from: 'collectionThree', 
      localField: 'packageDetails.ids',
      foreignField:'examId',
      as:'userExamDetails' 
}},
{   '$lookup': { 
      from: 'collectionFour', 
      localField: 'packageDetails.exams',
      foreignField:'_id',
      as:'examDetails' 
}},
{   '$project': { 
       'packageDetails': '$packageDetails',
       'userExamDetails': '$userExamDetails',
       'examDetails': {
           '$filter': {
              input: "$examDetails",
              as: "examDetails",
              cond: { 
                '$eq': [ "$$examDetails._id", 
                         "$userExamDetails.examId"] 
                  }
            }
         }
      }
}
])`

Comment: It wont work because both `examDetails` and `userExamDetails` fields are arrays

Comment: Yeah, its array. When I keep a value instead of "$userExamDetails.examId" as ObjectId("") the result is getting. How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would suggest a couple of changes to your pipeline. Replace your last [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) pipeline with an **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** operator and since `userExamDetails` field is an array, use the **[`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/)** operator as your conditional operator for the array filter.

The last pipeline stage should be as follows:

```
{ '$addFiels': {
    'examDetails': {
        '$filter': {
            'input': '$examDetails',
            'as': 'exam',
            'cond': {
                '$setIsSubset': [
                    ['$$exam._id'],
                    '$userExamDetails.examId'
                ]
            }
        }
    }  
} }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but what I want is the reverse, of this. I don't want any values in $examDetails which is in $userExamDetails. The common field between is _id & examId!